# iText to Aspose PDF Conversion. What to do for footer conversion?

Tags: aspose.pdf

Our original generation library is using PdfPageEventHelper in iText to render the page footer with something like page x of y.

How would I go about doing the same thing using Aspose's PDF library instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can add text stamp in PDF documents using Aspose.PDF for .NET. Also, it allows you to specify X,Y position for the stamp. Following code snippet can be used to add the Text Stamp in PDF:

```
// Open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("AddTextStamp.pdf");

// Create text stamp
TextStamp textStamp = new TextStamp("Sample Stamp");
// Set whether stamp is background
textStamp.Background = true;
// Set origin
textStamp.XIndent = 100;
textStamp.YIndent = 100;
// Rotate stamp
textStamp.Rotate = Rotation.on90;
// Set text properties
textStamp.TextState.Font = FontRepository.FindFont("Arial");
textStamp.TextState.FontSize = 14.0F;
textStamp.TextState.FontStyle = FontStyles.Bold;
textStamp.TextState.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
textStamp.TextState.ForegroundColor = Aspose.Pdf.Color.FromRgb(System.Drawing.Color.Aqua);
// Add stamp to particular page
pdfDocument.Pages[1].AddStamp(textStamp);

// Save output document
pdfDocument.Save("AddTextStamp_out.pdf");
```

*PS: This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.*